# Le mot « sur » devant le nom d'une ville

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu, toponymes

> À très vite sur Paris !
>
> Il a vécu sur Nancy.

Dans les phrases ci-dessus, le mot « sur » est évidemment l'équivalent de l'anglais « *in* » mais je ne l’ai jamais vu jusqu’à hier (et deux fois, rien de moins !)

Est-ce très courant ?  Peut-on l’utiliser de manière interchangeable avec « en » ou « à » ?

Comment: C'est courant depuis 5~6 ans. Ce n'est utilisé que pour les villes.

Comment: Merci oli.  C'est l'argot alors ? Est-ce très familier, le ton ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas une utilisation canonique/standard de la langue française. C'est juste à la mode depuis quelques années. Beaucoup de mes amis avaient l'air assez fiers d'utiliser cette expression. Ça doit faire "cool".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### À

La préposition normale devant un nom de ville est *à*.

### Sur

L'utilisation de la préposition *sur* est controversée. Il y a au moins trois écoles de pensées sur son sens :

- Cela ne se dit pas. Par exemple la plupart des participants sur [ce fil de discussion](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=617172) considèrent « sur Paris » comme fautif.
- Utiliser *sur* plutôt que *à* étend la portée, cela signifie qu'on inclut explicitement la banlieue. C'est le sens que [propose Stéphane Gimenez](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7239).
- Utiliser *sur* se rapporte à la ville dans son ensemble, plutôt qu'un point précis de la ville. La banlieue peut être incluse ou non, il n'y a ni plus ni moins d'ambiguïté qu'avec *à*. C'est le cas au moins dans mon idiolecte, et à Paris c'est un usage répandu. Par exemple, si on dit à un agent immobilier qu'on cherche un appartement « sur Paris », cela signifie n'importe où à Paris même, mais pas en banlieue.
- Utiliser *sur* traduit un mouvement. C'est notamment le dans des contextes militaires (une armée qui marche *sur* un territoire, le territoire étant celui qu'elle veut envahir)

Contrairement à ce qu'affirment des gens mal informés, l'utilisation de la préposition *sur* n'est pas un phénomène nouveau. Elle se répand cependant depuis la fin du 20<sup>e</sup> siècle.

> [MM. les Libraires […] voudront bien […] indiquer une maison sur Paris où ils soient bien connus.](http://books.google.fr/books?id=BDEQAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA340&dq=%22maison+sur+Paris%22) (*Le Télégraphe et Petites Affiches Littéraires*, 1810) [ensemble]
>
> [Hier, un train considérable d'artillerie anglaise a traversé Saint-Denis […] ; il s'est dirigé sur Paris.](http://books.google.fr/books?id=YpTLWKUseb8C&pg=PT224&dq=%22sur+Paris%22) (1815, *Journal de Paris*) [mouvement (militaire) ou ensemble]
>
> [Les armées ennemies qui pénétreraient sur Paris](http://books.google.fr/books?id=XK4CAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA46&dq=%22sur+Paris%22) (Napoléon Bonaparte, *Les 35 Jours, ou Mémoires politiques sur la campagne de 1815*, 1820) [mouvement militaire]
>
> [Encre à écrire, de Paris sur le Hâvre](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Cm_DnWYM7JIC&pg=PA282&dq=%22sur+Paris%22) (*Du Canal maritime de Paris à Rouen*, 1829) [ensemble, banlieue ou mouvement ?]
>
> [« Elle donnait des consultations médicales dans le voisinage et même assez loin sur Bezons. »](http://books.google.fr/books?id=AzIqAQAAIAAJ&q=%22habite+sur+Paris%22&dq=%22habite+sur+Paris%22) (*L'Atelier du Roman*, 2002) [ensemble, usage réel critiqué par celui qui le cite]
>
> [Les parents de mon père ont eux aussi leur maison sur Paris.](http://books.google.fr/books?id=BueJGD84N6IC&pg=PA32&dq=%22maison+sur+Paris) (Christy Prestone, *De l'ombre à la lumière*, 2006) [banlieue]
>
> [C'est comme les gens qui disent : *maintenant, j'habite sur Paris*, ça me flanque aussi le cafard. Je ne sais pas pourquoi, je les vois suspendus au-dessus de nous, sans doute.](http://books.google.fr/books?id=JANYmTR4DpoC&pg=PT23&dq=%22habite+sur+Paris%22) (Alain Teulié, *À part ça, les hommes vont bien..., 2010) [banlieue ou ensemble, usage critiqué par un personnage]

[Marina Yaguello](http://books.google.fr/books?id=wQUIGqW-xEQC&pg=PA95&dq=%22habite+sur+Paris%22) (*Petits faits de langue*, 1998) dit de l'usage de *sur* qu'« il est beaucoup plus compatible avec les verbes de processus qu'avec les verbes d'état ». Pour [Marie-Anne Paveau et Laurence Rosier](http://books.google.fr/books?id=9bEcAQAAIAAJ&q=%22habite+sur+Paris%22&dq=%22habite+sur+Paris%22) (*La langue française : passions et polémiques*, 2008), l'usage de *sur* a actuellement tendance à se répandre des verbes de mouvement aux verbes d'état, avec toujours la nuance que *sur* inclut la banlieue.

[Jean-Jacques Franckel et Denis Paillard](http://books.google.fr/books?id=wQUIGqW-xEQC&pg=PA95&dq=%22habite+sur+Paris%22) (*Grammaire des prépositions*, 2007) sont du même avis, parlant de « faible acceptibilité » pour *il habite sur Paris* : « Dans *aller sur Paris*, Paris désigne une direction et non le point de destination ». Ils proposent une autre nuance : « Avec *travailler sur*, le sujet du procès se présente comme se trouvant dans un rapport temporaire à Paris […] *il habite à Orléans mais travaille sur Paris* ». (Pour ma part, je comprends cette phrase comme signifiant Paris ou sa banlieue, et non un caractère temporaire.) [Émilie Pauly](http://books.google.fr/books?id=E7hm4zbCgH8C&pg=PA287&dq=%22habite+sur+Paris%22) (*La polysémie: réflexion théorique, méthodologique et application à la lexicographie : l'exemple des verbes aller, partir et tirer en français contemporain*, 2011) met en avant le sens inclusif de la banlieue.

[Logambal Souprayen-Cavery](http://books.google.fr/books?id=NoBS60islHMC&pg=PA166&dq=%22habite+sur+Paris%22) (*L'interlecte réunionnais: approche sociolinguistique des pratiques et des représentations*, 2010) cite *sur* + ville comme un usage réunionnais fautif.

### Dans

On peut aussi utiliser *dans* devant un nom de ville, mais cela à un sens particulier : cela signifie à l'intérieur de la ville, par opposition à sa banlieue. Suivant les cas il peut être plus idiomatique d'ajouter *même* après le nom de la ville. Ainsi « dans Paris » couvre la commune de Paris alors que « à Paris » peut signifier Paris même ou Paris et sa banlieue plus ou moins éloignée.

### En

En ancien français et en provençal, [on utilisait *en* devant les noms de villes](http://www.lexilogos.com/en_avignon.htm). Ceci n'est plus le cas en français moderne à deux exceptions près : *en Avignon* et *en Arles* sont encore utilisés quelquefois, mais même pour ces villes l'usage est vieilli et la préposition courante est *à*.

Comment: À part avec l'idée de mouvement, c'est un usage que j'ai remarqué en arrivant en France à la fin des années 1990 et que j'ai tendance à associer avec des personnes originaires ou ayant vécu longtemps à Paris.  Il me semble rare pour les autres personnes, et suscite assez souvent chez elles des commentaires.

Comment: Pour les villes ayant encore leurs remparts c'est plus compliqué.

Answer (score 5):

Cette utilisation controversée de **sur** est apparue il y a quelques décennies.

Suivant les cas ce **sur** peut indiquer:

- Une imprécision = à Paris et aux alentours.
- Une limitation dans le temps = temporairement à Paris.
- Une direction = vers Paris mais sans que ce soit forcément la destination finale.

Dans le dernier cas, **sur** est utilisé avec le verbe aller: « Je vais sur Paris ».

Comment: La troisième forme ressemble pas mal à "mettre le cap sur Paris". De sorte qu'en plein Atlantique qqn pourrait dire "Nous sommes sur Paris"; mais il ne pourrait le dire en survolant Paris. Intéressant!

Comment: @Amphiteóth Il dirait plutôt « Nous allons sur Paris ». Je modifie ma réponse pour clarifier ce troisième cas.

Answer (score 2):

Dans les cas que tu cites « sur » est un raccourci pour « dans la région de ». En particulier ça ne veut pas nécessairement dire « dans ».

Avec « on se donne rendez-vous sur Paris », on comprend « quelque part à l'endroit qui nous arrangera le mieux, en région parisienne ».

C'est d'un usage courant et plutôt informel, mais je n'irais pas jusqu'à dire que c'est familier.

On ne trouve quasiment jamais la préposition *en* devant un nom de ville (sauf cas exceptionnels comme *en Avignon* où elle remplace *à*). La préposition *à* est par contre très courante, bien plus courante que *dans*, et elle donne une précision intermédiaire : par défaut on comprendrait « à l'intérieur de la ville » mais on n'insiste pas sur ce point.

Comment: « En Avignon » s'entend en effet souvent mais c'est un parisianisme popularisé par les médias. À Avignon et aux alentours, on dit « à Avignon  ».

Answer (score 2):

Au Canada, cet emploi de *sur* est inconnu. Si l'on entend quelqu'un l'utiliser, on peut être *« sûr »* qu'il est Européen.

Comment: J'ai choisi cette orthographe délibérément.