# loger ou me loger

Tags: sens, terminologie

A

R1:  Ce qui concerne le sujet de logement, je vais loger, chez un ami qui a déjà pris, depuis un moment, un appartement quelque part à (ou bien "sur") NOM_DE_VILLE

R2:  Ce qui concerne le sujet de logement, je vais me loger, chez un ami qui a déjà pris, depuis un moment, un appartement quelque part à (ou bien "sur")  NOM_DE_VILLE

B

C'est vrai que Paris, c'est un peu particulier dans ce contexte, mais par contre si on prend une autre ville comme Nîmes par exemple, dans ce cas, on enchaîne la phrase avec "quelque part à Nîmes" "quelque part dans Nîmes" ou bien "quelque part sur Nîmes".

De mon point de vue je vois "à" comme plus correct et vous qu'est-ce que vous en pensez ?

Comment: Je ne comprends pas sur quoi porte la question. C'est sur la préposition devant le nom de la ville ? Si oui c'est un doublon : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7238/le-mot-sur-devant-le-nom-dune-ville

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A** La question doit d'abord être formulée comme suit;

> Qu'est-ce que tu vas faire **au sujet** du logement?

Le verbe « se loger » signifie « prendre un logement, trouver un logement », c'est à dire un appartement ou une maison; tout ce qui peut être trouvé chez un ami est une partie d'appartement, une chambre avec une cuisine et une salle de bain en commun; donc cela ne correspond pas trop bien et le verbe le plus convenable est le premier. Il est nécessaire cependant de reformuler la phrase, qui a plusieurs problèmes. Parmi d'autre possibilités la suivante convient.

> R1: En ce  qui concerne le sujet du logement c'est résolu, je vais loger chez un ami qui a  depuis un moment un appartement quelque part à (ou bien "sur") NOM_DE_VILLE.

On trouve les propos suivants concernant l'emploi de « sur » en rapport avec la [fonction de localisation](http://www.slate.fr/story/148410/sur-vous-etes-sur).

> «Je suis sur Paris introduit un effet d'approximation, qui peut englober la région parisienne, à la différence de “je suis à Paris” où l'on se situe forcément dans la capitale. Et cela traduit aussi l'évolution d'un emploi de mouvement –je vais sur Paris– à celui d'une localisation. C'est une étape de plus dans ce que le mot suggère.»

D'après cette source, l'usage n'est pas fermement établi mais il semble que par « sur Paris » dans certains cas, les gens veuillent dire  « Paris et ses abords ». Je l'utiliserais donc pour indiquer que l'appartement n'est pas exactement dans Paris mais en banlieue. C'est une préposition que l'on utilisait ainsi il y a au moins soixante-dix années.

**B** Je suis pratiquement certain qu'il n'y a pas de problème pour les grandes villes, qui ont toutes des banlieues (Bordeaux, Marseille, Lyon, Paris, Toulouse); 
si l'appartement est **dans** la ville même  on enchaîne la phrase avec « quelque part à Nîmes » ou « quelque part dans Nîmes »; « quelque part » est plutôt inutile;  « à Nîmes » or « dans Nîmes » est suffisant. Pour y revenir disons que dans ce cas où l'appartement se trouve dans une petite localité très près d'une ville comme Nîmes on dira « à côté de Nîmes » ou « dans les abords de Nîmes » ou même « dans le voisinage de Nîmes » et aussi d'après **jlliagre**<sup>1</sup> (commentaires) « sur Nîmes ».

Il n'est pas question de correction selon mon point de vue.
 
1. Si vous voulez spécifier que la location est dans la ville même « à » et « dans » sont parfaits et la seule possibilité.
2. Si vous voulez spécifier sans ambigüité que la location est dans les abords de la ville **il ne faut pas utiliser « sur »**; dans tous les cas une des expressions citées ci-dessus ou une autre de même signification est nécessaire.
3. Si pour une grande ville vous utilisez « sur », ce que vous pouvez faire, vous indiquez un plus grand ensemble conteneur et votre interlocuteur ne saura pas si c'est dans la ville même ou bien en dehors.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Commentaire de jlliagre : La restriction d'utilisation de sur appliquée à Nîmes n'a pas lieu d'être. Il n'y a aucun problème a dire je cherche une maison à louer sur Nîmes, l'usage est clairement établi.</sub>

Comment: Merci beaucoup cependant on dit sur NOM_de_VILLe ou bien à NOM_de_VILLe? par exemple sur Paris ou bien à Paris?

Comment: @famas https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7238/le-mot-sur-devant-le-nom-dune-ville

Comment: Encore une fois merci beaucoup, je vois bien ce que vous ..bon c'est vrais que Paris c'est un peu particularité dans ce contexte, mais par contre si on prend une autre village genre Nime  par exemple, dans ce cas, on enchaîne la phrase avec "quelque part à Nime" ""quelque part dans Nime" ou bien "quelque part sur Nime"...moi de mon point de vue je vois "à" est plus correcte et vous qu'est ce que vous pensez?

Comment: A quoi ça sert de mettre des commentaires si personne ne les lit. Il n'était pas très utile de répondre à la question B qui a déjà été posée maintes fois ici. Quant à monter ou descendre quelque part. Tout dépend d'où on se trouve. On peut monter à Nîmes quand on se trouve à Marseille, et de la plupart des régions de France, on **descendra** à Marseille ou à Nîmes. Si l'on part de Corse ou du sud de l'Italie, on pourra aussi très bien monter à Marseille.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, c'est vrai, ce que j'ajoute est contenu dans la réponse, mais c'est une petite partie et pour l'extraire de la réponse il y a beaucoup à lire qui est sans intérêt; j'ai préféré répéter cette petite partie avec des détails qui s'applique à la présente question. On ne trouve « monter à » que pour Lyon et Bordeaux et Paris. Pour Toulouse et Marseille on ne trouve rien; le TLFi donne « [En parlant de provinciaux se rendant notamment dans la capitale] Aller du sud au nord. » ; il y a quelque chose de bizarre : peu de cas pour « descendre à Paris », énormément de cas pour « monter ».

Comment: Il n'y a rien de bizarre, il suffit de regarder une carte de France; Paris est au nord de la très grande majorité du territoire français. Ceux qui montent à Bordeaux sont dans les Landes et ceux qui montent à Lyon sont dans la vallée du Rhône, et on peut descendre à Paris quand on est à Lille, comme on descend à Lyon, Marseille, Nice ou sur la côte quand on est à Paris.

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai bien pensé à ça mais je me suis dit que la concentration de population dans la région au-dessus de Paris aurait toujours été beaucoup plus importante; la population du Massif Central et des Alpes doit être négligeable il me semble en comparaison avec celle des plaines au-dessus de Paris; il faudrait que je consulte des données démographiques. Oui, ça se tient https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9mographie_de_la_France#/media/File:France_densit%C3%A9_2009.jpg

Comment: Non, à part la région lilloise, les plus grandes concentrations de population française sont au sud de Paris (Lyon, Marseille, Toulouse, Nice, Bordeaux, Rennes, Nantes, etc.); Strasbourg est elle aussi légèrement plus au sud que Paris, mais vu l'écart de longitude, je ne pense pas qu'on y dise je monte ou je descend à Paris, probablement juste je vais à Paris.

Comment: D'autre part, la restriction d'utilisation de *sur* appliquée à Nîmes n'a pas lieu d'être. Il n'y a aucun problème a dire *je cherche une maison à louer sur Nîmes*, l'usage est clairement établi.

Comment: @jlliagre Je parlais de votre explication; elle se tient.