# Pierre habite (à) Paris

Tags: usage, prépositions

Est-ce que le verbe *habiter* peut être utilisé indifféremment avec ou  sans la préposition *à*? Plus spécifiquement : est-ce que les phrases *Pierre habite Paris.* et *Pierre habite à Paris.* sont toutes les deux correctes ? S'agit-il d'une question d'usage ancien opposé à un usage moderne ?

J'ai toujours cru que la préposition *à* était nécessaire avec ce verbe. Mais en ce moment je travaille un cours de français (assez vieux) dans lequel on insiste sur l'utilisation sans *à*. Peut-être  s'agit-il du langage du début du XXème siècle ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“J'habite Lille” or “j'habite à Lille”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7589/jhabite-lille-or-jhabite-%c3%a0-lille)

Comment: @None techniquement, ma question est plus complexe, car je demande aussi s'il s'agit de langue moderne vs. ancienne, et la reponse ci-dessous adresse cette point. Mais merci pour le lien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les deux se disent et la forme sans « à » l'emportait jusqu'à présent (pendant le 19ème siècle et le 20ème), mais tout d'un coup il semblerait y avoir eu un revirement, ou une tendance vers la normalisation (après une lente baisse pour la première, et une lente augmentation pour la seconde) et c'est la forme avec « à » qui l'a emporté pendant un certain temps ; on peut voir cela dans [cet ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+habite+Paris%2Cil+habite+%C3%A0+Paris&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20habite%20Paris%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cil%20habite%20%C3%A0%20Paris%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cil%20habite%20Paris%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cil%20habite%20%C3%A0%20Paris%3B%2Cc0).

[Lyon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+habite+Lyon%2Cil+habite+%C3%A0+Lyon&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20habite%20Lyon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cil%20habite%20%C3%A0%20Lyon%3B%2Cc0) (phénomène similaire pour « lyon »)

*Pour les villes suivantes il n'y a pas de préposition (dans les livres), mais on peut quand même l'utiliser, dans la langue parlée ou écrite.*

[Bordeaux](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+habite+Bordeaux%2Cil+habite+%C3%A0+Bordeaux&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20habite%20Bordeaux%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cil%20habite%20Bordeaux%3B%2Cc0), [Marseille](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+habite+Marseille%2Cil+habite+%C3%A0+Marseille&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20habite%20Marseille%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: On entend aussi régulièrement "j'habite sur xxx" en tout cas en Belgique

Comment: @LaurentS. En Français métropolitain la préposition « sur » n'est pas rare dans ce contexte linguistique ; cependant, une signification particulière peut y être attachée, il ne s'agit plus de « à xxx même » ; elle est donc d'usage douteux, mal établi. Cela a fait l'objet d'une question dont les réponses, je crois, traitent  le sujet une fois pour toutes. Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/q/7238/17649