# Descendre dans / sur / à la vallée

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

> Où vas-tu ?
>
> Je vais descendre **dans** la vallée.

Antidote propose trois possibilités *descendre **dans** la vallée*, *descendre **vers** la vallée* et *descendre **sur** la vallée*. Quelle option est la meilleure ? À mon avis, la première et la deuxième. Serait-il aussi possible d'écrire *descendre **à** la vallée* ? Je pense que non...

Comment: Tout me semble possible selon la topographie et les circonstances.   *à* est cependant le moins vraisemblable.

Comment: @None, d'accord, merci.

Comment: vers ne signifie pas qu'on ait atteint ladite vallée.

Comment: Il faut éventuellement tenir compte du mode de locomotion (pied, ski, en rappel, planeur etc...). *Vers* ne dit pas si l'intention est d'aller jusqu'à la vallée (*à* ici parce que *aller*), arrêt en chemin possible.

Answer (score 2):

> *Je vais descendre **dans** la vallée* : le plus courant, c'est ma destination ou au moins une étape

> *Je vais descendre **vers** la vallée* : il s'agit uniquement d'une direction. Je vais peut-être m'arrêter ou partir dans une autre direction avant d'y arriver.

> *Je vais descendre **sur** la vallée* :  rare, je suis peut-être en deltaplane... On emploie aussi de plus en plus ***sur*** pour désigner une direction ou une destination plus vague (voir [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7253/1109) les usages similaires de *sur*, mais appliqué à un nom de  ville).

> *Je vais descendre **à** la vallée* : rare, registre plutôt relâché.

Answer (score -2):

Les trois sont corrects mais l'option « à » n'est pratiquement pas usitée. ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=descendre+dans+la+vall%C3%A9e%2Cdescendre+%C3%A0+la+vall%C3%A9e%2Cdescendre+sur+la+vall%C3%A9e%2C+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdescendre%20dans%20la%20vall%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdescendre%20%C3%A0%20la%20vall%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdescendre%20sur%20la%20vall%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdescendre%20dans%20la%20vall%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdescendre%20%C3%A0%20la%20vall%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdescendre%20sur%20la%20vall%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0))

[image]

Cet ngram surestime encore la fréquence de « à » ; on s'aperçoit que cette préposition est utilisée presque seulement dans le langage religieux. Pour « sur », c'est la même chose, c'est une préposition qui est utilisé très souvent dans son sens propre (le soir/la nuit/le brouillard/la lumière/… descend sur la vallée)

« Sur » ne signifie pas que la destination est le point que le complément de la préposition exprime ; c'est seulement le point *vers* lequel le mouvement est fait.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sur)) **A.** − [Après un verbe exprimant un déplacement]
> **1.** [Le compl. désigne un point de l'espace, un lieu]
> **a)** [Le compl. désigne un objectif]
> ♦ Marcher sur Rome; lancer une attaque, un raid sur une position ennemie. Les derniers tanks, peu à peu cachés par une bosse du terrain, foncent sur les lignes républicaines (Malraux, Espoir, 1937, p. 633).

Pratiquement, donné le sens propre de « descendre », la seule possibilité est « dans ».
Aus sens figuré « à » et « chez » sont courants. (« [descendu au Ritz](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=descendu+au+Ritz&share=&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3) »).

Comment: descendre au Ritz n'est pas le même sens que le descendre dans la vallée la question. Et pour chez, comment ça marcherait?

Comment: Cette réponse ne tient pas compte de ce qu'est une vallée. Et il s'agit de descendre ici, pas de marcher. *Marcher sur*  sur n'a rien à faire ici !

Comment: @Lambie « chez » n'ira pas avec les hotels mais c'est la préposition qui convient pour les résidences (« il est descendu chez son voisin », par exemple). C'est un avertissement: au sens figuré la préposition « à » est courante.

Comment: @None « Descendre » est un verbe de mouvement et pour descendre de cette façon (sens propre) il faudra bien marcher ou faire marcher un cheval, ou faire rouler un véhicule. La vallée ne comprend en pratique que la partie la plus basse des pentes, celle qui est plus ou moins habitable.

Comment: Descendre dans un hôtel (ou chez des amis ...) veut dire séjourner, rien à voir avec descendre dans la vallée, où c'est un mouvement (vers le bas) qui est décrit.

Comment: @None « Descendre chez quelqu'un » ne signifie pas « séjourner », seulement « aller chez quelqu'un ». Évidemment, ça n'a rien à voir, excepté que ça ajoute une précision, celle qu'il ne faut pas généraliser. Ce n'est qu'un détail dans ma réponse.  « Descendre dans un hotel » non plus: "Y aller (en descendant de voiture) afin d'y séjourner". ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/descendre))

Comment: Justement afin d'y **séjourner**. Rien ne dit que le locuteur ici veuille séjourner dans la vallée ou seulement la traverser. Et dans la vie il n'y a pas que le TLF (qui est une image historique,  [Loger, au cours d'un voyage. Descendre chez des amis, à l'hôtel](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/descendre).

Comment: @None 1/ Je  ne dis pas que c'est le même verbe, mais je dis que c'est le verbe _au sens figuré_, et ce n'est qu'un détail. 2/ Ce n'est pas de ma faute si les lexicographes du TLFi et ceux du Robert ne sont pas d'accord et, de plus, en ce qui concerne ce terme particulier (descendre chez untel), je le connais personnellment comme voulant dire, non pas « loger chez untel », mais comme signifiant « aller chez untel ». « Image historique » ne signifie pas grand chose ; c'est un dictionnaire paru il y a quelques vingt-cinq ans et on ne refait pas une langue en vingt-cinq ans.